# How do I catch a 404 response and use it to control program flow?

Tags: javascript, api, httprequest

I have access to two APIs. The first (and better API) responds with 404 for certain types of input. If the first API responds with 404 I want to send a request to the second API.

The log shows this after a 404:

```js
{
insertId: "0987654321"
labels: {2}
logName: "projects/my-awesome-project/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"
receiveTimestamp: "2022-11-01T21:41:50.570143002Z"
resource: {2}
textPayload: "Exception from a finished function: HTTPError: Response code 404 (NOT FOUND)"
timestamp: "2022-11-01T21:41:50.251844Z"
trace: "projects/my-awesome-project/traces/1234567890"
}
```

I'm guessing that the code will look something like this:

```js
try {
  async function callFirstAPI() {
    const response = await got(url, options).json();
    // if successful do stuff with the data

  callFirstAPI();
  }
} catch (error) {
  if (error.textPayload.includes('404') {
    callBackupAPI();
  }
}
```

What doesn't work is this. Nothing logs when the API throws a 404.

```js
try {
  async function callFirstAPI() {
    const response = await got(url, options).json();
    console.log(response); // nothing logs

  callFirstAPI();
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error!!! " + error); // nothing logs
}
```

Is `catch` not firing because a `404` response isn't considered an error? I.e., the `callFirstAPI` ran without crashing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. Here's the working code:

```js
async function callFirstAPI() {
  try {
    const response = await got(url, options).json();
    // if successful do stuff with the data
  } catch (error) {
    await callBackupAPI();
  }
}

callFirstAPI();
```

I had `try` in the outer block, `async` in the middle block, and `await` in the inner block. The correct syntax is `async` in the outer block, `try` in the middle block, and `await` in the inner block. This is explained near the end of the [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) documentation.

I hate to think how many years I've been using the incorrect syntax! This is the first time I've wanted to do something with a `404` response. The code will run with the incorrect syntax, it'll just never go to the `catch` block, i.e., errors won't be handled.

And the `error` log doesn't contain `404` so `if (error.includes('404')` won't do anything. Just put your backup code in the `catch` block and it'll run, no need for `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function in your try block isn't actually running.

You're just declaring the function, but never invoking it.

Try something like this:

```js
try {
  async function callFirstAPI() {
    const response = await got(url, options).json();
    console.log(response); // nothing logs
  }

  firstCallApi() // NOTE: ADD THIS LINE
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error!!! " + error); // nothing logs
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't show the full code.

Comment: My answer still holds.

You have to still surround the invocation of the function with a try/catch block